# SMS body in iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, sms

I need to send an SMS from my iphone app. the body of the SMS is created programatically. so when i tap on a button the SMS application should get opened with my message pre-typed in it. anybody knows how to do it? need help

Thanks in advance.
Shibin

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the SMS body. The only things you can do from your code, as per the official SDK, is 1) to open the SMS application:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"sms:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

and 2) to set the phone number for a new message:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"sms:+12345678901";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the body in iOS 4. Please cf [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/SystemIntegrationGuide_iPhoneOS/UsingSystemMessagingFacilities/UsingSystemMessagingFacilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009529-CH5-SW3).